# Copy one to another textbox and change letters

Tags: php, javascript, textbox, copy

Im using this script to copy from one to another textbox. I dont know how to make when i write in box A that what will be copied in box B to be changed. exp. Letter A ti be 001, letter E to be 002, letter V to be 008. I dont care if its in php or JavaScript.

Thanks for your time and help

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copy_data(val){
     var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
     document.getElementById("copy_to").value=a
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name ="a" id="copy_from" onkeyup="copy_data(this)"/><br>
To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name ="b" id="copy_to"/><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript has a [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function. You wouldn't do it with PHP unless you want to make an AJAX call to the server to do the translation on every key press, which would be a lot of unnecessary calls to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fljBt) is a small sample of javacript replace function using your code, it's probably what you are looking for.

just changed:

```
document.getElementById("copy_to").value=a
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("copy_to").value=a
    .replace(/a/g, '001') // the letter/string, you code
    .replace(/b/g, '002') // ...
```

Comment: thanks this work but just for first entered letter if i enter "ABVABV" i get 001002003ABV

Comment: Fixed, just changed string to RegExp Object

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is with a JavaScript function, using an object to map the particular character to a specific code to be inserted (in this case the character `a` maps to `001`, and so forth):

```
var keysToCodes = {
    'a': '001',
    'b': '002',
    'c': '003',
    'd': '004'
};

function transferAndAmend(source, target, e) {
    if (!source || !target) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var e = e || window.event,
            keynum = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which,
            key = String.fromCharCode(keynum),
            char = keysToCodes[key] ? keysToCodes[key] : key;
        target.value += char;
    }
}

var source = document.getElementById('one'),
    target = document.getElementById('two');

source.onkeypress = function(e) {
    transferAndAmend(this, target, e);
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2faYy/2/).

This is tested, and seems to work, in Chrome 21 and IE 7, on Windows XP.